# Save site as template using client object model

Tags: client-object-model, site-template

I would like to reproduce the "Save site as template" action with the client object model. Can someone give me a hint how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "Save site as template" is not possible with the client object model (it IS possible with the server object model).

If you look at the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web` class you'll see it doesn't have a `SaveAsTemplate` method like the server-side `SPWeb` class does.

Although I'm not familiar with these techniques, this may be a workaround:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/08/23/site-provisioning-techniques-and-remote-provisioning-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I guess, there's no way to run code based on the server object model from the client side, even if I am site collection admin?

Comment: One way you could run server side code from the client side is to develop a web service (server side code required). The web service would call the `SPWeb.SaveAsTemplate` method and would take in the parameters that the `SaveAsTemplate` method needs. Or if you're able to develop a server side solution then just create an application page with code behind that calls `SaveAsTemplate`. If developing server side code/solution isn't an option for you then I'm afraid you're stuck.

Comment: Sounds bad( No way to save web as template vias JSOM?..