# SharePoint Online - Save site template as .wsp file locally programmatically by CSOM C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I would like to save the site template as .wsp file locally programmatically by CSOM C#.

I know how to save it as a .wsp file from SharePoint online, but does anyone who has any idea how to do the process programmatically? I prefer using CSOM C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to achive this using CSOM C#.

Its only available with [SPWeb.SaveAsTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.saveastemplate.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (SSOM).

And there is no possible available method in CSOM for this.

For more information you can check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/164096/30145) answer.